# Fined first div above me by attr

Tags: jquery, find, attr

How to find the first match div by attr ?

```
<div isactive=1>
</div>
<div isactive=1>
</div>
<div isactive=0>
</div>
<div isactive=1>
</div>
```

I am in the last div and need to get the closet one above me by attr isactive=1, in this case the second one is match.

Comment: *"need to get the closet one"* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```js
var $this = $('div:last')
var $el = $this.prevAll('div[isactive="1"]').first();
$el.css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div isactive=1>
  1
</div>
<div isactive=1>
  2
</div>
<div isactive=0>
  3
</div>
<div isactive=1>
  4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this as shown :-

HTML :

```
<div isactive=1>
  1
</div>
<div isactive=1>
  2
</div>
<div isactive=0>
  3
</div>
<div isactive=1>
  4
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('div:last').siblings('div[isactive=1]:last').css('color', 'red');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/05q3sgzd/)

OR

```
$('div:last').prevAll('div[isactive=1]:first').css('color', 'red');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bzhw7wok/)

OR

```
$('div:last').prevAll().filter('div[isactive=1]:first').css('color', 'red');
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztxvcfg5/2/)

OR

```
$('div:last').siblings().filter('div[isactive=1]:last').css('color', 'red');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztxvcfg5/)